# Options for an immediate 90° elbow from a PEX barb options

Tags: plumbing, water, pex

[image]I'm trying to install some freeze free hose bibs on my house. I purchased the shortest ones available, knowing it doesn't often freeze around me. The issue is that the hose bib intends to connect with the water source straight out of the back, my water supply comes from below, and my wall isn't very thick.

So my question is, what is the shortest length way to add an 90° elbow onto my hose bib's existing PEX barb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what's illustrated, return this one and get a threaded hose bib/sillcock, then use a threaded-to-PEX elbow.

To do it in PEX, you'll be over by two PEX barb lengths minimum, no way around that.

Alternatively, use PEX like PEX, not like rigid pipe, and make a loop of more than minimum bend radius to change direction.

Comment: I was hoping there would be some kind of solution that I was overlooking, like a PEX street elbow or something, but I guess not.